# Scald: themable atom reference – where to find image path etc.?

Tags: entities, nodes, scald

I can't find a way how to get an atom reference's values (image path etc.) into my theme template. When printing the node array I do get the SID for the referenced image, but I just don't know how to load the actual details.

Or is it possible by simply using `node_load` or `entity_load` or the like? Any pointers gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question one of scald's issue pages – and it's not really complicated. Either it's just not well documented, or I just didn't see it:

This gets the `SID` from the node's array:

```
$img = $vars['node']->field_teaser_image['und'][0]['sid'];
```

And this fetches the atom reference's object:

```
$atom = scald_atom_load($img);
```

This is how I then load the title of the atom reference image inside `template.php`:

```
$vars['img_title'] = $atom->title;
```

And the actual filename is inside another object `base_entity`:

```
$vars['img_filename'] = $atom->base_entity->filename;
```

Hope this may help somebody some day.